# Confusion regarding Confidence Intervals

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics

Suppose we have $2$ population parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, such that the $90$% ( symmetric ) confidence intervals for $p_1$ and $p_2$ are given by $ (0.411, 0.498) $ and $(0.473, 0.567)$ respectively. Now, according to the original question ( copied verbatim ) , supposing that the $90 $% interval for $p_1$ lies entirely below the interval for $p_2$, how confident are we to conclude that $p_1 < p_2$?

Now, assuming that I have understood the problem correctly, I feel that this question does not make sense to me because $(0.411, 0.498)$ does not lie completely behind $(0.473,0.567)$. The question is, am I right in claiming so?

Next, assuming the problem is simply "How confident are we to conclude that $p_1 < p_2 $ ", given their $2$ $90$% symmetric confidence intervals as above, how would we go about approaching it, if it is even possible?

Comment: Given a 90% CI for $p,$ you know $\hat p$ is the midpoint. If these are Wald intervals you can also deduce $n$ from there. (Do this for both intervals,) Then you can make 2 CIs of equal confidence levels (obviously lower than 90%) that _do not_ overlap. // Check your terminology: How can _parameters_ be independent?

Comment: oh, that was a typo, will fix it thanks! Shall think through what you said.